# Is there any ways I could improve ubuntu preformance?

Tags: games, performance

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Air 2014 and want to play some games on it; are there any tips or tactics I could use to maximize Ubuntu performance?

edit: I'm currently using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have recently notice some lag spike during my minecraft bed war sessions

Comment: And what performance problems did you notice?

Comment: @David Im currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have notice some lag spikes on my minecraft playing session

Comment: @Bodo Im currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have notice some lag spikes on my minecraft playing session

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.